# Bootstrap .col adjusts to screen size on desktop but not mobile

Tags: php, mobile, bootstrap-4

I made a photo gallery using bootstrap 4.

```
<https://rocallisa.xyz/photos>
```

It does show less images on 1 row depending on the screen width on desktop but when changing the screen width on mobile, it doesn't work.

```
<?php  foreach ($photos as $photo) { ?>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12 col gallery-col">
            <img class="gallery-image" src="<?php echo site_url(); ?>assets/images/<?php echo $photo['photo_name'];?>" alt="No Image Found"/>
        </a>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add this inside `head` tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

It is necessary in order to responsiveness to work.